# Back button on Action Bar crashing app android

Tags: android

Synposis: I have 3 activity (LoginActivity, MainActivity and EditProfileActivity). After Facebook login in my LoginActivity I srart the MainActivity. (Till this point the app is working perfectly correct with no error). I have a NavigationDrawer for my navigations, When I click on Edit Profile link from the NavigationDrawer it starts the EditProfileActivity.

Problem: When I click on the LeftArrow in the Top blue bar, the app crashes.

Please see the images:

**MainActivity**

[image]

**Navigation Drawer**

[image]

**EditProfileActivity**

[image]

**App Crash on clicking the top left arrow**

[image]

Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

package com.example.example;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String first_name = inBundle.get("first_name").toString();
        String last_name = inBundle.get("last_name").toString();
        String imageUrl = inBundle.get("imageUrl").toString();

        TextView nameView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameView);
        nameView.setText("" + first_name + " " + last_name);
        new DownloadImage((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)).execute(imageUrl);
        return true;
    }
    public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } else if(id == R.id.nav_user_edit){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: Post Your logcat rather than your screen designs.

Comment: better to put error log cat.!

Comment: Let me do that.

Comment: Unfortunately logcat shows nothing. There is no error

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your activities parent in the manifest file like this

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="fully qualified activity name" />
```

Make sure that you keep this meta data of your activity containing back button. Other wise its just like you are not telling you back button where to go !!

You have to add these two lines in your MainActivity.java file:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Add this in your onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method:

```
if (id==android.R.id.home)
        {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
```

Comment: so it the fully qualified activity name would be `com.example.example.MainActivity`. I'm very new to android so I'm asking.

Comment: Yeah its the fully qulified name

Comment: Where to add this 2 lines? Could you please update my MainActivity.java above. so that I can understand

Comment: on let me try this

Comment: Add them in your onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145846/discussion-between-bharath-and-subrata-banerjee).

Answer (score 0):

In your toolbar.xml set an imageview. Do like this i your toolbar.xml

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tv_header_title2"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/backbutton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
```

In MainActivity

```
 ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tv_header_title2);



and 


  img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: why would I do this?

Comment: There may be many reasons behind app crashing.. I need to see logcat. This will also help you. Just go to Toolbar.xml and add one imageview and simple make reference of it in MainActivity and setclick listener to it.